# Difference between ~ and ! in unix shell scripting

Tags: shell, regular-expression

Which operator should be used between ~ and ! while checking a regular expression in IF condition in shell scripting??

Will there be any difference between the two cases shared below ??

case 1:

```
if [[ $file_date != ^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$ ]]; 
then    
    echo -e "The file_date is not in the required format"; 
else
    echo "doing good";
fi
```

case 2:

```
if [[ $file_date =~ ^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$ ]]; 
then    
    echo -e "The file_date is not in the required format"; 
else
    echo "doing good";
fi
```

Comment: For a homework question like this it wouldn't have been terribly hard to try the two options yourself.

Comment: Please do some research before asking here. While we welcome basic questions, this is something that would have been trivial to find if you'd even spent a few seconds searching. Would you go to a mathematics forum and ask "Is there any difference between `+` and `-`?"

Answer (score 4):

Comparing `!=` and `=~` is like comparing apples to oranges.

`!=` roughly means "not equal", while `=~` means "matches".
You can read more about this operators under `[[ expression ]]` in `man bash`. Here's an excerpt of the most relevant sections:

> ```
>       When the == and != operators are used, the string to the  right  of
>       the  operator  is considered a pattern and matched according to the
>       rules described below under Pattern Matching,  as  if  the  extglob
>       shell option were enabled.  The = operator is equivalent to ==.  If
>       the shell option nocasematch is enabled,  the  match  is  performed
>       without  regard  to  the case of alphabetic characters.  The return
>       value is 0 if the string matches (==) or does not  match  (!=)  the
>       pattern, and 1 otherwise.  Any part of the pattern may be quoted to
>       force the quoted portion to be matched as a string.
>
>       An additional binary operator, =~,  is  available,  with  the  same
>       precedence  as == and !=.  When it is used, the string to the right
>       of the operator is considered an extended  regular  expression  and
>       matched accordingly (as in regex(3)).  The return value is 0 if the
>       string matches the  pattern,  and  1  otherwise.   If  the  regular
>       expression is syntactically incorrect, the conditional expression's
>       return value is 2.
> ```